# Distinct count basis condition for last 3 months

Tags: powerbi, distinct-values, running-count

| Outlet ID | Outlet Name | Order Date | Product | Qty | Net Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mum_1 | Prime Traders | 12th Oct 2022 | RoundBox | 3 | 300 |
| Mum_4 | Avon Trading | 13th Oct 2022 | Slice 100 | 10 | 1000 |

I have date wise transaction data for past 20 months for retail outlets.
Any outlet that has been billed in the last 3 months can be classified as an 'Available Outlet'.
Eg: Available outlets for Sept 2022 are the ones that have been billed at least once across July, August & Sept 2022.
Similarly I need to have ,month wise availability count in a column chart. Can someone please guide as to how can I write a DAX query for the same ?

Comment: Hello, would you mind putting your sample data in a table format in your post. That way it can be copy/pasted and you can receive help easier.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Comment: A picture is no sample data unless you want a solution with Photoshop.

Comment: Have added the table. Was doing it for the first time in SO. Please try and help regarding the query.

Comment: I think the solution would be somewhere along the lines of distinct count of outlet IDs where the sum of net value over last 3 months is greater than zero. But How do we write a DAX query for this ?